# Hide table row if cells with input are empty or zero

Tags: jquery, input, row, cell, hide

i'm trying to delete rows in a table that are empty but not in the full table only from "tr ("+x+"+5)" and from "td ("+i+"+7) input".

I was trying to sum the values from the row from the inputs and if the result is "0", "null" or "undefined". But i can't get it to work.

The table has right now 150 tr and 15 td but this should be set dynamicaly. The maximum to the bottom of the table from the 5th for "tr" and the maximum to the right for the "td" from the 7th.

```
$(".produkttabelle_alt tr:nth-child(n+5)").each(function(i, obj){ 

var sum = 0;

$(this).children("td:nth-child(n+7)").children().each(function(){ 

var input_val_sum = $(this).val(); 

sum += parseInt(input_val_sum); 
}); 


if ((sum != null) || (sum != "") || (sum != "undefined") || (sum != 0) ) {

$(this).closest(".old_row_tr").hide(); 

}});
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(".produkttabelle_alt tr:nth-child(5n)").each(function(i, row) {
  var sum = 0;
  $("td:nth-child(7n)", row).each(function(j, cell) {
    sum += parseInt($("input", cell).val());
  });
  if ((sum != null) || (sum != "") || (sum != "undefined") || (sum != 0)) {
    console.log("Hide Row " + ($(row).index() + 1));
    $(row).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="produkttabelle_alt">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please see: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

> Because jQuery's implementation of `:nth-` selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of `n` is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at `1`.

If you want to to target every 5th row, use `5n`. If you want to target every 7th cell, use `7n`.

**Update**

The Value of an input will always be a String, so it is unlikely to be `null` or `undefined`. It may be letter or some other chracter. So you may consider using `isNaN()` function.

```
if(isNaN(sum) || sum == 0){
  row.hide();
}
```

This will catch Empty or 0 value rows. Here is an example:

```js
$(".produkttabelle_alt tr:nth-child(5n)").each(function(i, row) {
  var sum = 0;
  $("td:nth-child(7n)", row).each(function(j, cell) {
    sum += parseInt($("input", cell).val());
  });
  if (isNaN(sum) || (sum == 0)) {
    console.log("Hide Row " + ($(row).index() + 1));
    $(row).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="produkttabelle_alt">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Test Row -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Test Row -->
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="14" /></td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="21" /></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the tip with the nth!
Every "td" has an input inside but some have no value applied to it. Could you help me out to hide the rows of which the inputs have no values? If even one value greater than zero is present i would need to keep the row.

Comment: @GAX simply update your IF statement. Right now you are using Not Equals (`!=`) for all your comparisons. You would switch it to Equals (`==`), so that if it does match, you hide that row.

Comment: It doesn't work :/ does not "hide" the rows with all empty inputs in the TDs

Comment: Thanks you very much! It is hiding now every 5th row :S

Comment: @GAX I am not able to replicate that. As you can see, my script only hides row 5 and row 15.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @Twisty i could figuere out the problem. Thanks you very much! This snippet now works for adding a class to rows that are empty or the sum of the children 7n is 0.

```
 $(".produkttabelle_alt tr:nth-child(n+5)").each(function(i, obj){
        var sum = 0;

        $(this).children("td:nth-child(n+7)").children().each(function(){
          var input_val_sum = $(this).val();
          sum += parseInt(input_val_sum);
            
        });
        
        if (isNaN(sum) || (sum == 0)) {
            
            $(this).closest(".old_row_tr").addClass("not_ordered");
        }   
});
```